# How could I change my WooCommerce shop page header background color?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Because page-id isn't working or showing in view-source. Also I can't find any page specific class.

I'm trying to change the background-color of the WooCommerce pages that don't have page-id including:

- Shop
- Checkout
- Product-categories

The page URL is: https://kampgaroo.com

I tried using the page id that I found in the dashboard/pages and it's not in the shop code.

Comment: I would suggest to inspect the website with the devtools of your browser and find a unique id or class you can change the color for in you stylesheet.

Comment: Trademark capitalization; acronym capitalization; grammar. Fixed title

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For category

```
 .tax-product_cat .site-header__masthead.masthead-v1 {
     background: #000 !important; }
```

For Shop

```
.woocommerce-shop .site-header__masthead.masthead-v1 {
    background: #000 !important;
}
```

For checkout

```
.page-id-147 .site-header__masthead.masthead-v1 {
    background: #000 !important;
}
```